# MongoDB Pipeline $lookup only works when hard coding object id

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm experiencing a weird issue in one of my MongoDB aggregation pipeline stages.

Here are the results from the previous stage:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6532b629454826446d8f399c"
    },
    "title": "Learning"
  }
  // ... more objects
]
```

When I define the next $match stage as follows (using hard coded ObjectID):

```
{
  from: "characterengagements",
  let: {
    tagId: { $toObjectId: '$$ROOT._id' },
  },
  pipeline: [
    { $match: { tags: ObjectId("6532b629454826446d8f399c") } },
    { $addFields: { testTagId: '$$tagId' } }
  ],
  as: "topCharacters"
}
```

I get the following output from the pipeline:

Notice that:

- this document was properly returned because the tags array field
  contains the object id specified above.
- testTagId displays the correct value (same value as I hard coded)

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6532b629454826446d8f399c"
    },
    "title": "Learning",
    "topCharacters": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "6532d773454826446dd2b967"
        },
        "character": {
          "$oid": "6532b63aacd66daa12860580"
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "$date": "2023-10-20T19:39:31.517Z"
        },
        "tags": [
          {
            "$oid": "6531c7d2fe4908d7ec87a58a"
          },
          {
            "$oid": "6532b5e6454826446d8ed08c"
          },
          {
            "$oid": "6532b629454826446d8f399c"
          },
          {
            "$oid": "6532b62c454826446d8f3de7"
          },
          {
            "$oid": "6532b74a454826446d91056b"
          }
        ],
        "testTagId": {
          "$oid": "6532b629454826446d8f399c"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  // ... more documents
]
```

The issue arises when I don't hard code this value and instead try to use $$tagId (which as shown above, was properly formatted):

```
{
  from: "characterengagements",
  let: {
    tagId: { $toObjectId: '$$ROOT._id' },
  },
  pipeline: [
    { 
      $match: {
        // $$tagId should be the same as the hard coded value above, as shown by adding testTagId to the output from above, however, I get different results.
        tags: '$$tagId'
      } 
    },
    { 
      $addFields: {
        tagIdWas: '$$tagId'
            }
      
    }
  ],
  as: "topCharacters"
}
```

The above returns no documents.

If anyone has encountered this issue before I'd greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/UC40Wi4SoVk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-join-pipeline), you must use the `$expr` operator to access the variable in the `$match` stage.

```
{
  from: "characterengagements",
  let: {
    tagId: { $toObjectId: '$$ROOT._id' },
  },
  pipeline: [
    { 
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $in: [
            "$$tagId",
            "$tags"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    { 
      $addFields: {
        tagIdWas: '$$tagId'
      }
    }
  ],
  as: "topCharacters"
}
```

Side note, I think converting to `ObjectId` seems unnecessary since the `_id` is `ObjectId`. You can simplify to:

```
let: { tagId: "$_id" }
```

If you use MongoDB 5.0 or above, you can use both [`localField` and `foreignField` with pipeline simultaneously](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#correlated-subqueries-using-concise-syntax).

```
{
  from: "characterengagements",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "tags",
  let: { tagId: "$_id" }
  pipeline: [
    { 
      $addFields: {
        tagIdWas: '$$tagId'
      }
    }
  ],
  as: "topCharacters"
}
```

Comment: Yong Shun, thank you for the detailed reply you really went above and beyond.